# Having problem on my Tic-Tac-Toe Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I was making a Console based Tic-tac-toe game. My script is given below:

```
game_board = [
    ["_", "_", "_",],
    ["_", "_", "_",],
    ["_", "_", "_",],

]

#This variable is made for checking eligible ans
eligible_ans = [0, 1, 2, 3]

#Game and is a variable by which game will continue or not
end = False


#Player list with all values
#player = [row, col, player num , state]
player1 = [0, 0, 1, False]
player2 = [0, 0, 2, False]

#Shows game board:
def show_gameboard():
    for num in range(3):
        print("|" + game_board[num][0] + "|" + game_board[num][1] + "|" + game_board[num][2] + "|")

#Takes eligible input from player
def get_move(player):
    x = 4
    y = 4
  
    while x not in eligible_ans and y not in eligible_ans:
        x = int(input("Enter your row: ")) - 1
        y = int(input("Enter your colum: ")) - 1

    player[0] = x
    player[1] = y

#Switches on the state item on player list
def switch_on_state(player):
    player[3] = True

def switch_off_state(player):
    player[3] = False

#Checks if the slot is empty    
def check_slot(player):
    if game_board[player[0]][player[1]] == "_":
        switch_on_state(player)
    else:
        while not player[3]:
            get_move(player)
            if game_board[player[0]][player[1]] == "_":
                switch_on_state(player)     

#Places the move
def move(player):
    if player[3] == True:
        if player[2] == 1:
            game_board[player[0]][player[1]] = "X"

        else:
            game_board[player[0]][player[1]] = "O"
    
    switch_off_state(player)

#Checks row for winner
def check_row():
    if game_board[0][0] == game_board[0][1] and game_board[0][1] == game_board[0][2]:
        end = True
    elif game_board[1][0] == game_board[1][1] and game_board[1][1] == game_board[1][2]:
        end = True
    elif game_board[2][0] == game_board[2][1] and game_board[2][1] == game_board[2][2]:
        end = True

#Check column for winner
def check_col():
    if game_board[0][0] == game_board[1][0] and game_board[1][0] == game_board[2][0]:
        end = True
    elif game_board[0][1] == game_board[1][1] and game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][1]:
        end = True
    elif game_board[0][2] == game_board[1][2] and game_board[1][2] == game_board[2][2]:
        end = True
    else:
        pass

#Check diagonal for winner
def check_diagonal():
        #Down to up check
        if game_board[2][0] == game_board[1][1] and game_board[1][1] == game_board[0][2]:
            end = True 

        #Up to down check
        elif game_board[0][0] == game_board[1][1] and game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][2]:
            end = True


#Checks for whole winner
def check_winner():
    check_row()
    check_col()
    check_diagonal()

#The main workarround
def main():
    i = 0
    while not end and i < 3:
        show_gameboard()
        print("Player1=> \n")
        get_move(player1)
        check_slot(player1)
        move(player1)
        check_winner()
        if end:
            print("Player 1 won")
            break
        print(end)

        show_gameboard()
        print("Player2=> \n")
        get_move(player2)
        check_slot(player2)
        move(player2)
        check_winner()
        if end:
            print("Player 2 won")
            break
        print(end)         #*****The problem is here******

        i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except:
        print("\nProgram Failed.\nTry again!!!\n")
```

**My question is why the *print(end)* shows the value of end as False even though somebody wins?**

***print(end)* is in the *main()* function where *"The problem is here"* written**

Even though someone wins and by the function *check_winner()*, the end variable should be True. But why still the end variable shows/contains False as value.

Comment: The only way that `print` statement can print anything is if `end` is `False`, because if it were `True`, you would have broken out of the loop via `break` in the body of the `if` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

end is a local variable. try to add:

```
global end
```

in the first line of check_row(), check_col() and in check_diagonal()
and in the main().

for example:

```
#Check column for winner
def check_col():
    global end
    if game_board[0][0] == game_board[1][0] and game_board[1][0] == game_board[2][0]:
        end = True
    elif game_board[0][1] == game_board[1][1] and game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][1]:
        end = True
    elif game_board[0][2] == game_board[1][2] and game_board[1][2] == game_board[2][2]:
        end = True
    else:
        pass
```

You can do this in another way, try to return the 'end' from these functions and receive the return value in main().

Comment: one more thing... Can I use `global end = True` in every if statement to do the same work?